# DBpedia, get country of a site having a latitude and longitude

Tags: rdf, latitude-longitude, sparql, dbpedia

I want to get the Country which contains a latitude and longitude. Currently, I have the query below which works,

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?lat,?long,?place WHERE {
:Taj_Mahal dbpprop:latitude ?lat .
:Taj_Mahal dbpprop:longitude ?long .
}
```

Now, how can I get the Country which contains this latitude and longitude using dbpedia?

Comment: You shouldn't use commas between variables in the `SELECT` clause, as explained in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15680198/error-in-sparql-query.

Answer (score 2):

if you already have the resource (Taj_Mahal) then you can use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?lat ?long (str(?place) as ?place) ?country1 ?country2 
  WHERE {
  :Taj_Mahal dbpprop:latitude ?lat .
  :Taj_Mahal dbpprop:longitude ?long .
  :Taj_Mahal dbpedia2:location ?place .
  OPTIONAL {:Taj_Mahal dbpedia2:country ?country1} .
  OPTIONAL {:Taj_Mahal dbpedia2:locmapin ?country2} .
}
```

[run query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=%20%20%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20?lat%20?long%20%28str%28?place%29%20as%20?place%29%20?country1%20?country2%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3aTaj_Mahal%20dbpprop%3alatitude%20?lat%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3aTaj_Mahal%20dbpprop%3alongitude%20?long%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3aTaj_Mahal%20dbpedia2%3alocation%20?place%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3aTaj_Mahal%20dbpedia2%3acountry%20?country1%7D%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%3aTaj_Mahal%20dbpedia2%3alocmapin%20?country2%7D%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0D%0A)

if you only have `lat` and `log`, you can use this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT str(?what) as ?what str(?place) as ?place ?country1 ?country2   
  WHERE {
  ?target dbpprop:latitude 27 .
  ?target dbpprop:longitude 78 .
  ?target dbpedia2:location ?place .
  ?target rdfs:label ?what .
  OPTIONAL {?target dbpedia2:country ?country1} .
  OPTIONAL {?target dbpedia2:locmapin ?country2} .

  FILTER (lang(?what) = 'en')
}
```

[run query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=%20%20SELECT%20DISTINCT%20str%28?what%29%20as%20?what%20str%28?place%29%20as%20?place%20?country1%20?country2%20%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20WHERE%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?target%20dbpprop%3alatitude%2027%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?target%20dbpprop%3alongitude%2078%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?target%20dbpedia2%3alocation%20?place%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20?target%20rdfs%3alabel%20?what%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B?target%20dbpedia2%3acountry%20?country1%7D%20.%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B?target%20dbpedia2%3alocmapin%20?country2%7D%20.%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%20%28lang%28?what%29%20=%20%27en%27%29%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%7D)

note, however, that this query works if the resource (*Taj Mahal* in this case) has `country`, `location` or `logmapin` properties set. this is not the case for all places.

Comment: I'm having a confusion, for many places, the latitude and longitude property is from different namespaces, e.g. for this resource http://dbpedia.org/page/Kaaba, it it doesn't have dbpprop:latitude but geo:lat, how can we deal with this. Is the solution performing a union of the property so that the available one is chosen?

Comment: That resource does have `dbpprop:latitude` and `dbpprop:longitude` properties (although the values are not as precise as those in `geo:lat` and `geo:lon`). You could try `{ ?target geo:lat <x> ; geo:lon <y> } UNION { ?target dbpprop:latitude <x> ; dbpprop:longitude <y>}`.

Comment: I'm just curious about one thing, why is it that same property is used from different namespaces??

Comment: `dbpprop:...` is automatically created for every field in Infoboxes, but the `geo:lat` and `geo:lon` are used almost everywhere in the Linked Data world. Therefore, for compatibility it makes sense to add these properties for latitude and longitude values.