# Error in SPARQL Query

Tags: rdf, sparql, dbpedia

I'm getting an error with my SPARQL query but can't find it out:

**Query**

```
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> 
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> 
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> 
PREFIX rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> 
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/> 
PREFIX : <http://dbpedia.org/resource/> 
PREFIX dbpedia2: <http://dbpedia.org/property/> 
PREFIX dbpedia: <http://dbpedia.org/> 
SELECT DISTINCT ?lat, ?long { 
:Taj_Mahal dbpedia2:latitude ?lat . 
:Taj_Mahal dbpedia2:longitude ?long }
```

**Error**

```
Encountered " "," ", "" at line 9, column 21.
Was expecting one of:
     ...
     ...
    "from" ...
    "where" ...
    "(" ...
    "{" ...
```

Any suggestion??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you should not put a comma between `?lat` and `?long`

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?lat ?long { 
    :Taj_Mahal dbpedia2:latitude ?lat . 
    :Taj_Mahal dbpedia2:longitude ?long 
}
```

[run query](http://dbpedia.org/snorql/?query=SELECT%20DISTINCT%20?lat%20?long%20%7B%20%0D%0A%3aTaj_Mahal%20dbpedia2%3alatitude%20?lat%20.%20%0D%0A%3aTaj_Mahal%20dbpedia2%3alongitude%20?long%20%7D%0D%0A)